# MySQL Заполнить новый столбец отобранными значениями из одного столбца по условию зависимости от второго столбца

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть некоторый список тегов `transport` = ("авто", "пешеход")
Нужно найти элементы этого списка в поле `tagname` (всегда может быть только один тег), и если такой элемент нашелся, то для каждой строки с тем же `productid` добавить в новую колонку `transport` данный элемент

Т.е. из таблицы

| productid | tagname |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | авто |
| 31 | колесо |
| 50 | пешеход |
| 50 | ботинки |
| 50 | кроссовки |
| 31 | двигатель |

нужно получить следующую таблицу с помощью запроса в MySQL:

| productid | tagname | transport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | авто | авто |
| 31 | колесо | авто |
| 50 | пешеход | пешеход |
| 50 | ботинки | пешеход |
| 50 | кроссовки | пешеход |
| 31 | двигатель | авто |

Comment: @Mike Да, на основе productid. Я перепутал местами в последних двух строках их. Сейчас поправил, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Задан список transport = ("авто", "пешеход"). Нужно найти элементы этого списка в tagname. Например, нашли такой элемент для хотя бы одной строки с productid = 31 (нашли "авто"), значит всем строкам, где productid = 31, нужно присвоить такой элемент ("авто")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен мультитабличный UPDATE

```sql
UPDATE
  mytable t,
  (
    SELECT
      productid,
      tagname
    FROM
      mytable
    WHERE
      tagname IN ('авто', 'пешеход')
  ) tags
SET
  t.transport = tags.tagname
WHERE
  t.productid = tags.productid;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddd4bb9/1)

Или так

```sql
UPDATE
  mytable tags
  JOIN mytable t ON (
    t.productid = tags.productid
  )
SET
  t.transport = tags.tagname
WHERE
  tags.tagname IN ('авто', 'пешеход')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58d633/1)

---

А если вам не нужен UPDATE, а нужен обычный SELECT, так это вообще просто

```sql
SELECT
  t.productid,
  t.tagname,
  tags.tagname AS transport
FROM
  mytable tags
  JOIN mytable t ON (
    t.productid = tags.productid
  )
WHERE
  tags.tagname IN ('авто', 'пешеход')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f27cec/1)

Comment: О, спасибо, а можно получить результат в SELECT, не изменяя саму таблицу?

Comment: @Rugert так тогда вообще все просто